# Minecraft RecipeManager search function, how to skip to a page?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to look at recipes in a server I'm on using the `/rmrecipes <material>` command, but some of them have multiple pages that I can flip through. Unfortunately, I can only go to a certain number of pages before it seems to forget that I was looking at something and resets. Is there a way to skip to a certain page?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's like the /help command,in which you have to write
/help 1
/help 2
/help 3
...
so it can be
`/rmrecipes <material> 1`
`/rmrecipes <material> 2`
`/rmrecipes <material> 3`
...
Try it.

Comment: @mineman Did this answer your question? If yes, please mark it as accepted, so that this question doesn't remain open.